# L1 memories being recalled in my L2

Tags: terminology, psycholinguistics, second-lang-acquisition

The situation is as follows: I have been studying my L2 for approximately 4 years. I have spent a total of 10 months immersed in the L2 environment. My current stint has been for 5 months and counting.

To clarify the topic, I have been recalling past events, that were originally in English, in Japanese (my L2). This would be fine if it didn't happen without me being conscious of the event (at least initially). This has happened a number of times but I never took note until today. I was particularly tired from the various stressors of life and my current job situation. Therefore, I thought that it may have been a lapse as a result of exhaustion. However, that's when I realized that this has happened on at least 3 or more occasions. I'm not as much concerned as I am curious.

Is there a name for this process? Is this a normal experience for everyone?

Comment: I assume L stands for Language.  I have the same experience in various forms. Often I do not know what language I am reading, and I may buy a book in the wrong language for another person, even though I am looking for the right language. It may require a conscious act of will to know what language I am actually using, on some occasions. No idea what it is called ...

Comment: Whatever language is most convenient is used for memory playback, no matter what language the scene involved. It's actually a mark of deep immersion if your unconscious is finding Japanese the simpler solution. I remember recalling a very dramatic scene from my stay in Mexico -- one where I was certain no English had been used, because I was the only one who spoke it involved in the conversation -- several months after I returned, and being bemused by the fact that the people were all speaking English, which I knew was impossible. The mind is an interesting place.

Comment: @babou In discussions of language acquisition, L1 refers to one's native languages and L2 to languages learned later in life.